# How to create neat DAGs in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, directed-acyclic-graphs

I would like to create a DAG in R using `ggdag` and `daggity`, but I would like them to be:

1. the text labels to be centralised
2. not overlapping with any texts

Here are my codes:

```
library(ggdag)      # For plotting DAGs
library(dagitty)    # For working with DAG logic

simple_dag_with_coords_and_labels <- dagify(
  outcome ~ treatment + confounder1 + confounder2 + confounder3 + confounder4,
  treatment ~ confounder1 + confounder2 + confounder3 + confounder4,
  exposure = "treatment",
  outcome = "outcome",
  labels = c(outcome = "Outcome", treatment = "Deranged LFT", 
             confounder1 = "DM", 
             confounder2 = "Days on PN", 
             confounder3 = "Presence of\nhepatotoxic drugs", 
             confounder4 = "Presence of\nline sepsis"),
  coords = list(x = c(treatment = 0, confounder1 = 1, confounder2 = 1, confounder3 = 1, confounder4 = 1, outcome = 2),
                y = c(treatment = 0, confounder1 = 1.7, confounder2 = 1, confounder3 = -1, confounder4 = -1.7, outcome = 0)))

ggdag_status(simple_dag_with_coords_and_labels, 
             use_labels = "label", text = FALSE, stylized = TRUE,
             check_overlap = ) +
  guides(fill = FALSE, color = FALSE) +  # Disable the legend
  theme_dag()
```

Here is the graph obtained:
[image]

As you can see, the text labels are not centred and aligned with the centre of the circles. It is also covering the lines, especially the "Deranged LFT".

Answer (score 0):

An option could be creating an extra dataframe with the coordinates of your labels and plot them using `geom_text` like this:

```r
library(ggdag)      # For plotting DAGs
library(dagitty)    # For working with DAG logic
library(ggplot2)

df_labels = data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2),
                       y = c(0, 1.7, 1, -1, -1.7, 0),
                       label = c("Deranged LFT", "DM", "Days on PN", "Presence of\nhepatotoxic drugs", "Presence of\nhepatotoxic drugs", "Outcome"))

ggdag_status(simple_dag_with_coords_and_labels, 
             text = FALSE, stylized = TRUE,
             check_overlap = TRUE) +
  guides(fill = FALSE, color = FALSE) +  
  geom_text(data = df_labels, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), inherit.aes = FALSE, size = 2) +
  theme_dag()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Is it possible to make the circles bigger so that the words can be seen more clearly? Or to keep the text label (as in the original post) but centralised and consistently placed either above or below the circles. Thanks

Comment: Hi @HNSKD, Yes sure! You could use the argument `node_size` in `ggdag_status` to make the circles bigger.